# Compilation error - package does not exist - Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependency-management, playframework-2.4

I have the following file structure:

```
root-folder
--.idea
--folder1-java-console-application (module 1)
----src
------main/java/my/package/App.java
----pom.xml
--folder2-play-framework-2-ui (module 2)
----app
------controllers
--------Application.java
```

**Application.java** depends on **my.package.App.java**. So, I import this package like this:

**Application.java:**

```
import my.package.App;

public class Application extends Controller {
    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

Also I [added](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d1552849e472) **module 1** in dependency list of **module 2**.

Now, when I start Play-server, I have no any errors. But, when I open URL `http://localhost:9000/`, I get the error: **Compilation error - package my.package.App does not exist**.

I get confused. I can compile my code, but I get trouble in runtime. I try play framework in first time in my life. So, probably I don't know some information about this.

The full start project command (from IDEA) is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt-global-plugin3stub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath C:\Users\Mike\.IntelliJIdea14\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar xsbt.boot.Boot run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) check your Play application works without dependencies;

(b) check your Play application has module #1 in class path, when started - see play framework [dependencies management](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/dependency);

(c) build module #1 with maven (maven guides + google will help);

(d) check your module #1 jar contains my/package/App.class file.

Comment: (a) is done. (b) - I am not sure, that Play application has to have module 1 in class path, because module 1 is just *.java files. (c) there is no jar "module ", It is just folder and *.class files in runtime.

Comment: You start the app from IDE. The first line in console describes full Java command to start your application. Add it to your question description.

Comment: It seems you don't use maven. In project settings > module #2 add explicit dependency to module #1

Comment: I use maven only in module 1. I have already added dependency - http://snag.gy/LEt7n.jpg

Comment: The last try - create lib/ folder in play application and place module #1 jar file here (see link in step b).